# ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref

Tags: pycharm, exe, py2exe

When I run a py file in pycharm to make an .exe file I get the error in .exe.log file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E2Tools.py", line 17, in <module>
File "E2Tools.py", line 17, in <module>
File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module
File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module
File "logging\__init__.pyc", line 26, in <module>
File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module
File "weakref.pyc", line 14, in <module>

ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
```

Could anyone please tell me how to fix that?